# Implementing a background thread on web application to check the time every minute

Tags: java, web-services

I want to implement a thread working on the background of my web application, that checks the time every minute to do some required job, i tested this code on normal java application :

```
    int milisInAMinute = 6000;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Runnable update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            update.run();
        }
    }, time % milisInAMinute, milisInAMinute);one minute.update.run();
   }
```

Where should i add it on my java based web application? and is this method correct, or should i use a different method?

Comment: Does this job need to have a user associated with it? Or is it a automated background job?

Comment: my application is about handling tasks for users, users have to specify time, when this time is reached, i want form my application to handle it's task, what i want is how to check every second who's time has reached?

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't use this in production code. You will have a lot of problems create custom schedulers in the web application. Use [Spring scheduling](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).